# Databricks SQL Query Nested Json column which is stored as string

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

So, I have data in a column which looks like this:

```
select additional_data,typeof(additional_data) as type 
from table
```

[image: sample data].

I am interested in querying the field `appName`. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I have tried:

```
select additional_data.content.appName
from table
```

but that gives me an error saying

```
can't extract value from additional_data#10527.content: need struct type but got string
```

since content is string, I then tried casting it to struct , using something like

```
select additional_data, 
       cast(additional_data.content as struct)
from table
```

but that gave me

```
DataType struct is not supported
```

I then tried to check if the content could be changed to struct, but I couldn't with

```
select additional_data,
named_struct('content', additional_data.content),
typeof(named_struct('content', additional_data.content))
from table
```

The type remained the same as in the original case with the content still being a string

[image: stillstring]

I also looked at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-json-path-expression), but even that I could not get to work

If I did this

```
select additional_data,
additional_data:content
from table
```

it errored with

```
Cannot resolve 'semi_structured_extract_json_multi(table.additional_data, '$.content')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'table.additional_data' is of struct<content:string> type.
```

Can someone help with how I can do this correctly and of course efficiently?

Let's assume that the original table can't be altered and the end users can only use pure sql (no spark dataframes)

I can of course answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two options:

1. More prone to breaking changes , if new properties are added, as we have to define an exact schema. Something like

```
select from_json(additional_data.content,'searchPhrase string, isResultFound string, appName string').appName
from table
```

2. Use an approach which is immune to changes

```
select get_json_object(additional_data.content,  '$.appName') 
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to convert your first line to a structured value, extract the content from `content`, then again parse your string to another structured value (through `from_json`), then extract the values from the key-value pair.

This should do the trick:

```scala
val df = spark.sql(
  """select content,
    |from_json(content, 'struct<searchPhrase:string>').searchPhrase as searchPhrase,
    |from_json(content, 'struct<isResultFound:string>').isResultFound as isResultFound,
    |from_json(content, 'struct<appName:string>').appName as appName
    |from (select from_json(additional_data, 'struct<content:string>').content as content from table)
    |"""
    .stripMargin)
```

or in Dataset API:

```scala
ds = ds
  .withColumn("content", expr("from_json(additional_data, 'STRUCT<content:STRING>').content"))
  .withColumn("other_json", expr("from_json(content, 'struct<searchPhrase:string,isResultFound:string,appName:string>')"))
  .withColumn("searchPhrase", expr("other_json.searchPhrase"))
  .withColumn("isResultFound", expr("other_json.isResultFound"))
  .withColumn("appName", expr("other_json.appName"))
  .drop("other_json", "additional_data")
```

Final result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-------+
|content                                                              |searchPhrase|isResultFound|appName|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-------+
|{"searchPhrase": "shor", "isResultFound": "true", "appName": "phone"}|shor        |true         |phone  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it. However as soon as I do ````from_json(additional_data, 'struct<content:string>')````, it errors out saying ````Cannot resolve 'from_json(max_order_sessions_with_progressivesearch.additional_data)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'max_order_sessions_with_progressivesearch.additional_data' is of struct<content:string> type.````

Comment: But then I tried using from_json, like you did, and got it working through something like this ````select *, from_json(additional_data.content,'searchPhrase string, isResultFound string, appName string').appName````. I am however not very happy with this, as I have specify an exact schema; and since additional data is basically a nested json, new elements could be added anytime and if that happens, this code will break

Comment: A colleague also pointed towards the function ````get_json_object````. Using that is much less complicated and less prone to break, if new elements are added. so, something like ````select get_json_object(additional_data.content,  '$.appName') from table ````

Comment: Thanks for the effort though. Appreciated